Property expansion Soap UI Parameters not working
I am testing the API https://www.deckofcardsapi.com and trying to get a response from Draw request as parameter to another request.
${Draw#Response#$cards[0].code} is not working - I'm getting an error:
{
   "success": false,
   "error": "You must specify cards to add to the pile."
}

I want to get the code value from this JSON response:
{
   "success": true,
   "deck_id": "c0lf9b6fxcjj",
   "cards": [   {
      "code": "5S",
      "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/5S.png",
      "images":       {
         "svg": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/5S.svg",
         "png": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/5S.png"
      },
      "value": "5",
      "suit": "SPADES"
   }],
   "remaining": 51
}


have you tried extracting it out side?
